# Angular: Is possible to remove template event "(click)" with a directive?

Tags: angular, listener, angular-directive

Im creating template dynamically, I have a directive that will check the user permissions *(basically read & write)*.

If my user only has "read" permissions it is possible to remove the attached click event?
[image]

This is the code of the directive, I tried adding a click listener in the directive and stop the event inside of the directive, but the click event is still triggered.

This is the directive's code.
[image]

Comment: Can you put the code in the question as text, not as images?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your logic here a little bit.

First, you can have `@Input() permissions: string[]` as you want.

Second, in the (click) event, instead of calling `value.clickEvent()` directly, you can create a method  call click, and you can have a if-else/switch-case condition here to trigger the click event or not. It'll help you.

component.html

```
<button (click)="handleClick()"></button>
```

component.ts

```
// adding new function
handleClick(): void {
   const canRead = this.permissions.some(per => per === 'read');

   if (canRead === false) {
      this.value.clickEvent();
   }
}
```

Happy coding!